# Is Angular service really singleton?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular service like this:

```
angular.module('MyModule')
    .factory('SharedData', function( ){
        return {
            session_id: undefined, 
            getSessionId: function () {
                return this.session_id;
            },
            setSessionId: function (new_id) {
                this.session_id = new_id;
            },
        };
    }).
    controller( 'MyController', ['SharedData', function( SharedData ){
            console.log( "Retrieved session id = " + SharedData.getSessionId()); 
               // getting undefined here!
    }]);
```

I called the service at an earlier time in another module like this:

```
angular.module( 'bootstrapper' )
    factory("AnotherService", function(){
          var injector = angular.injector(['MyModule', 'ng']),
              shared_data = injector.get('SharedData');
              shared_data.setSessionId( getUrlParameter('SESSIONID'));
          ...

 });
```

The console output result is undefined.

I think the `SharedData` in 'MyController' and the `SharedData` in 'AnotherService' are not the same object. However, people are all saying that Angular services are singletons. Are they real singletons?

---

More details about my modules: 
I used module 'bootstrapper' to manually bootstrap the other module 'MyModule':

```
angular.module( 'bootstrapper' )
    .run(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyModule']);
    });
```

Comment: Yes, they are different in your case. Services are singletons within the **same** application. This is not your case.

Comment: @dfsq Do you mean module when you said 'application'?

Comment: Not really a module. The application is what bootstrapped as the app. It can be `ngApp` or manual `angular.bootstrap`. Looks like you have two apps?

Comment: @dfsq In response to your question, I have added more details in the question body. Please find added part below the horizontal rule. Thanks!
    Then the question is :  What the standard way to pass data between applications?  Please write your solution as an Answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what DOM element are you using for the 'bootstrapper' app?

Comment: @georgeawg I simply created the DOM programatically: `var appContainer = document.createElement("div");` and then manually bootstrap the 'bootstrapper' module: `angular.bootstrap(appContainer, ['bootstrapper']);`

Comment: Factory providers like `AnotherService` are lazily instantiated. The `$get` function only runs if the service is injected somewhere. And the return from the `$get` function is cached and only run once. Hence **providers** are **singletons**. If you had injected `AnotherService` somewhere, you would have gotten a Return Enforcement Exception because your `AnotherService` doesn't return anything.

Comment: This is not very good approach you chose, imo. Better to defined `bootstrapper` application and make it initialize `sharedData` service and share it with other dependent modules (not applications like in your case). Much simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide constants to the app at bootstrap time as a module dependency.

```
angular.module( 'bootstrapper' )
    .config(function () {
        var sessionIdProvider = function ($provide) {
             $provide.constant("SESSIONID", getUrlParameter('SESSIONID'));
        };
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyModule', sessionIDProvider]);
    });
```

For more information see the [AngularJS $provide Service API Reference -- constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant).

**Update**

You can also skip the `bootstrap` app and use a config block in the `MyModule` app.

```
angular.module( 'MyModule' )
    .config(function ($provide) {
        $provide.constant("SESSIONID", getUrlParameter('SESSIONID'));
});
```

For more information see the [AngularJS angular.module API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module),

Comment: Will it be possible to provide the whole service to 'MyModule' similarly? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but its better to do it in a config block of the `MyModule` app. See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`angular.factory` are not constructors, it seems to me that using `angular.service` instead would solve your problem,

Comment: Original code was fine, your closure version is clumsy and should not be used. Both service and factory are the same thing in concern to `this` context. So it can't be the issue.

Comment: sorry for the question @dfsq, which part is clumsy? out of curiosity

Comment: @dfsq I removed the harmful part of my answer, I was wrong, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Well it was not harmful, just original code is fine, and you proposed less elegant closure solution, although it's unlikely to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a bit, I feel that you have chosen not very good approach. It's better to define `bootstrapper` application and make it initialize `sharedData` service, then share it with other dependent modules. Note, not *applications* like in your case, but *dependent modules*. This would be much simpler and cleaner.

Here is an example setup that would allow nice "modularization":

```js
/**
 * Bootstrapper application.
 */
angular.module('bootstrapper', ['dashboard'])
    .factory('sharedData', function() {
        return {
            sessionId: undefined,
            setSessionId: function(value) {
                this.sessionId = value;
            },
            getSessionId: function() {
                return this.sessionId;
            }
        }
    })
    .controller('BootController', function(sharedData) {
        this.name = 'Bootstrapper app';
        sharedData.setSessionId('34sd-3sdf345g-23a2421b');
    });
    
/**
 * Apllication kicked off by main bootstrapper.
 */
 angular.module('dashboard', [])
    .directive('dashboardModule', function() {
        return {
            controller: 'DashboardController as dashboard',
            template:
              "<div>" +   
              "    {{ dashboard.name }} sessionId: {{ dashboard.sharedData.sessionId }}" +
              "</div>"
        };
    })
    .controller('DashboardController', function(sharedData) {
        this.name = 'Dashboard';
        this.sharedData = sharedData;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="bootstrapper" ng-controller="BootController as boot">
    
    <h3>{{ boot.name }}</h3>
    
    <dashboard-module name="dashboard"></dashboard-module>
  
    <!-- <some-other-module></some-other-module> -->
    
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for writing the detailed solution. However, this is not passing data between applications. I have to manually bootstrap the main app because I need to fetch some configuration info from server first, and then configure the main app according to this info.